# C++ Return double or int from function

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes the exact same args, but sometimes I'd like for it to return a double and other times I'd like for it to return an int. What's the proper way to do that?

I could do function overloading, but the declarations of overloaded functions must differ from each other by the types and/or the number of arguments in the argument list. These would be identical so function overloading would not apply (I don't think).

```
double calc( int value, int add, double mult )
{
     // Sometimes I want this to return int. Sometimes double.
     return (value + add) * mult;
}
```

I'd rather not cast to int when that's the type I expect or write two functions (one for ints, the other for doubles). Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you elaborate in what circumstances you want an `int` versus a `double`?

Comment: How would you use that function? Can you provide examples for both cases?

Comment: @templatetypedef - Yes, sometimes the mult arg is 1.0, at other times it is 1.375, etc. When it's 1.0 I'd like to return an int. When it's 1.375 I'd like to return a double.

Comment: @user1200129: why don't you always return double? It's just 4 more bytes. I think your machine can handle this. ;)

Comment: @Idov - Yes, that's what I do now. But when calling applications get 1.0 rather than 1. They complain or crash.

Comment: @user1200129: ok, you defined your interface to return double and your clients (whoever they might be) crash because *THEY DON'T USE IT CORRECTLY*, so you want to change it? this is just wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a second function:

```
int calcInt(int value, int add, double mult) {
  return calc(value, add, mult);
}
```

Or you can use a template:

```
template <class myType>
myType calc(int value, int add, myType mult) {
  return (value + add) * mult;
}
```

You can't create a different function with the same name and arguments; the compiler wouldn't know which one you wanted to invoke.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer the "calcInt" version, the other isn't explicit enough from a code readabilty point of view. It may mask logic/precision issues further down the track.

Comment: Agreed.  But sometimes it's helpful to know what the options are.

Answer (score 5):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T calc (const int value, const int add, const U mult)
{
    return static_cast<T> ((value + add) * mult);
}

calc<double> (1, 2, 1.7); // returns double
calc<int> (1, 2, 3.4); // returns int
```

Comment: Thanks, I want calc( 1, 2, 1.0 ); to return an int and calc( 1, 2, 1.375 ); to return a double. The mult arg will always be 1.0 or 1.375. It's never just 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for maintaining precision or something like that, I would define my own type -- `Number` or something like that, and manage whether it is an int or double internally.

Comment: It is sort of related to that. A calling app wants an int. I give it 1.0 and it freaks out because it expects 1, not 1.0 so I was trying to make the function return 1 when the calling app wants an int.

Answer (score 1):

just do it as a double or use a template and let the compiler figure it out.

If your int = 1
Then double = 1.0

They are the same number and double will help with the precision.

Just have it return a double. It uses more memory, but it's local scope so who cares?